# Not able to find find xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I'm not able to find the xpath for the text from the below xml. I need to get the text, "ABCD" for the analysisId.

```
<ns1:Results>
<ns1:Type>string</ns1:Type>
<ns1:Key>resolution</ns1:Key>
<ns1:SimpleValue><![CDATA[<ResultAnalysisList priority="0000" analysisId="ABCD" displayName=" ">
<Group id=""
|
|
</ns1:Results>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath

Comment: Your XML code is incomplete, please fix it. Are you trying to get data in CDATA node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using pure XPath v1.0 (version that selenium supports, if I remember correctly).

Text inside CDATA is not parsed. It is treated as plain text. So in XPath processor's point of view, there is no elements or attributes that you can access using XPath within CDATA.

Related: [Xpath to the tag inside CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991496/xpath-to-the-tag-inside-cdata)

---

If CDATA section contains well-formed XML, you could try to get the whole CDATA content using XPath first, and then pass it as a separate XML to your XPath processor (2 steps parsing).

Just FYI, XPath 3.0 has [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-functions-30-20140408/#func-parse-xml) function which can be used for this purpose, something along this line :

```
//ns1:SimpleValue/parse-xml(.)/ResultAnalysisList/@analysisId
```

<sub>xpath 3.0 demo: http://xpatheval.apphb.com/y6Ln4drA4</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//ns1:SimpleValue,'analysisId="'),'"')
```