# retrieve xpath content from div id

Tags: html, xpath

How do I retrieved the text inside article-field1?

```
<title>Testing</title>
  <link>http://example.org</link>
  <description>Description</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <lastBuildDate>Mon, 13 Feb 2012 00:00:00 +0000</lastBuildDate>

  <item>
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link>http://example.org/2012/03/27/</link>
    <description><![CDATA[
        <div id="article-field1"><a href="http://example.org/test1">Test 1</a></div>
        <div id="article-field2">123</div>
    <pubDate>Tue, 2 Mar 2012 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
  </item>
```

I've tried to use

```
//description/div[@id="article-field1"]/text()
```

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: You posted a malformed XML (`<![CDATA[` does not have a corresponding close tag), which is probably not the same XML you're trying to run XPath against. If this is really your input XML, then it is no wonder XPath does not return any results. Also, if your `div`s are inside of `<![CDATA[` block, there is no way to get the specific `div`, as they're just text content, not the part of the input XML tree.

Comment: I cannot see where your CDATA section ends. There should be two closing brackets. In fact, the sample is missing some closing tags for the second description. It's just malformed. Please correct.

Comment: @shadow: The best advise is to remove the `<![CDATA[` from the document -- then your XPath expression may select the wanted nodes on the new document.

Answer (score 5):

```
//description/div[@id="article-field1"]/a/text()
```

If the malformed `CDATA` tag is removed, a root element is added and the corresponding 'description' tag is closed. This assumes an error of partially pasting the original XML, which is all that makes sense given the expression. Basically, the original query was missing the `a` element.

This can be verified at http://www.xpathtester.com/.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see your data are in a CDATA tag. This prevents parsing its content.

See [How do I retrieve element text inside CDATA markup via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a single call of plain-vanilla XPATH processor.

You have two choices:

1. Uses a specific XPATH processor that implements the [dyn:evaluate()](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/) function (and this begs the question: What processor and version are you using?); OR
2. Use two calls. The first go get the text value of the /title/item/description node. The second, after loading the result of the first as a new XML document (with a few tweeks to convert the xml fragment into a proper xml document), is div[@id="article-field1"] .

Comment: Note: The content of the title/item/description node is pure character data, not XML, that is why "//description/div[@id="article-field1"]/text()" does not work.