# Hpple - Reading a tag with an attribute

Tags: objective-c, xml, xpath, hpple

I'm trying to parse a XML,

```
 <entry>
 <title type="html"><![CDATA[TITLE]]></title>
 </entry>
```

Using Hpple, I'm trying to read the

```
 NSArray *array = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//entry/title[@type='html']"];
```

But the returned value is null. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hpple is a wrapper over XPathQuery, you might want to check it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath#answer-570538)

**tl;dr** Try adding /text() to your XPath query.

Also it looks like Hpple's author uses a different function call to search by XPath in his [Unit Test for hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple/blob/master/UnitTesting/TFHppleHTMLTest.m); for example `NSArray * a = [doc search:@"//a[@class='sponsor']"];`, perhaps its worth to give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but now, instead showing _"(null)"_ in the NSLog, the application crash: _"index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"_;

Comment: Am I doing this right: _searchWithXPathQuery:@"//entry/title[@type='html']/text()"_?

Comment: For as far as the XPath is concerned, that looks alright. I've never used Hpple before so I wouldn't know about that however...