# xml data parsing using dom in android

Tags: android, dom, android-parser

how to parse this type of data using DOM? here some text is in CDATA and some text in normal.

```
<error><![CDATA[This Mobile number already registered]]> with a different ICNO ( Hotline Number: +993498347334 )</error>
```

Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing as a DOM Parser try this **factory.setCoalescing(true);**
This way the CDATA is removed.

If you need first what is inside CDATA i suggest to get the string from xml then make a substring starting with 
Hope it helps.

Comment: i am not getting your second line.. and i am getting the data which is in CDATA normally(not for the above said tag , for another one), but when it comes to the above said one I am not getting data.. only i am getting "with a different ICNO ( Hotline Number: +993498347334 )"

Comment: Sorry for delay... I think your answer is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath