# XPATH - Path to a node with conditions on different levels

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I've got the following XML structure and need to get the value in

```
<VALUE><![CDATA[PRUEBAS BPM]]></VALUE>
```

I need to check on two conditions :

1. Get to node FIELD[NAME="dependency"]
2. Get to FIELD[NAME="name"]

My XPATH is actually written like this

```
/TRAIL/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="dependency"]/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="name"]/PRIMITIVE/VALUE/text()
```

However, it doesn't bring any data.
Is my XPATH written wrongly somehow? How can I sort out the acces to that info in my xml?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here's my XML structure

```
<TRAIL>
  <ENTITY>
    <FIELD>
      <NAME>dependency</NAME>
      <ENTITY>
        <FIELD>
          <NAME>codigo</NAME>
          <PRIMITIVE>
            <VALUE><![CDATA[906]]></VALUE>
          </PRIMITIVE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD>
          <NAME>name</NAME>
          <PRIMITIVE>
            <VALUE><![CDATA[PRUEBAS BPM]]></VALUE>
          </PRIMITIVE>
        </FIELD>
      </ENTITY>
    </FIELD>
  </ENTITY>
</TRAIL>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

As an extra I must add I'm using this XPATH to retrieve info directly from a database.
This is my SQL statement (delta is the table's column containing the XML)

```
SELECT XPATH('(/TRAIL/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="dependency"]/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="name"])/PRIMITIVE/VALUE/text()', CAST( SUBSTRING( delta FROM position('<TRAIL>' IN delta) FOR char_length(delta)) AS ml ) ) FROM aud_huella_expediente
```

Comment: you have unnecessary **)** in your xpath after `/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="name"]`

Comment: So was it! I have corrected it in my post

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is correct (remove `text()` from the end of the expression and test it [online](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx)). Most likely your problems arise from the CDATA section, see [How do I retrieve element text inside CDATA markup via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to remove that right paren:

```
/TRAIL/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="dependency"]/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="name"]/PRIMITIVE/VALUE/text()
```

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid when copying tha xpath I included that parenthesis by accident. The thing is I'm using the xpath in a SQL statement. This is the full SQL     : SELECT  XPATH('(/TRAIL/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="dependency"]/ENTITY/FIELD[NAME="name"])/PRIMITIVE/VALUE/text()',
         CAST(    SUBSTRING( delta FROM position('<TRAIL>' IN delta) FOR char_length(delta) )AS xml )
        )
        FROM aud_huella_expediente