# How do I find the text within an XML element with specific attributes?

Tags: php, xml, regex, wordpress

I'm looking to parse an export from wordpress using Regex to import it into a custom blog application. I've tried a number of ways to try to get to the data, but have been unsuccessful. I have:

`<category domain="category" nicename="category-name"><![CDATA[Category Name]]></category>`

I'm looking to find all of the text where: `<![CDATA[Category Name]]>` is. It also match the attribute with `domain="category"`, but I do not care what the "nicename" is. This is important because other `<category>` elements have `domain="post_tag"` in them, which I do not want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve element text inside CDATA markup via XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath)

Comment: heck, maybe even truplicate! so what

Comment: Sorry, not really what I was looking for. I wanted a regex solution, not to use another tool.

Comment: @ChrisG Hey man, no need to be sorry. You're `entitled` to ask for help. So what if it's a (groan) *possible* duplicate (BFD). Ask and hopefully, ye shall get answers. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisG - A regex solution is really not suited for what you're trying to do. It can work, but it's not very practical.

Comment: @PédeLeão yes, that's what it's looking like unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleXML:

[Demo](http://codepad.org/2d8W9FfM)

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($obj->category as $c)
{
   if($c->attributes()->domain == 'category')
   {
     echo (string)$c; // echo the content
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought about converting it to a simplexml object, but then I would have to re-write my whole import script. I'm using one that I wrote a while back that was compatible with WP at that time...using regex. Now with the upgrades that they have done, it no longer works correctly. I may have to abandon ship and re-write it anyways if I can't find a regex solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah as others have said, Regex is not really suited for the complexities of XML. Good luck :) This answer comes to mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags