# XPath - How to get image source from xml

Tags: xpath

Hello i have this xml

```
        <item>
        <title> Something for title»</title>
        <link>some url</link>
        <description><![CDATA[<div class="feed-description"><div class="feed-image"><img src="pictureUrl.jpg" /></div>text for desc</div>]]></description>
        <pubDate>Thu, 11 Jun 2015 16:50:16 +0300</pubDate>
    </item>
```

I try to get the img src with path: `//description//div[@class='feed-description']//div[@class='feed-image']//img/@src` but it doesn't work

is there any solution?

Comment: not going to work, because that html is inside a `cdata` block. it's basically a single large blob of text inside the `<description>` element. You'll have to extract the text content of `<description>`, then feed it into a NEW dom parser and do the `src` extraction on that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CDATA section escapes its contents. In other words, CDATA prevents its contents from being parsed as markup when the rest of the document is parsed. So the `<div>`s in there are not seen as XML elements, only as flat text. The `<description>` element has no element children ... only a single text child. As such, XPath can't select any `<div>` descendant of `<description>` because none exists in the parsed XML tree.

What to do?

If your XPath environment supports XPath 3.0, you could use [parse-xml()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) to turn the flat text into a tree, then use XPath to select `//div[@class='feed-description']//div[@class='feed-image']//img/@src` from the resulting tree.

Otherwise, your best workaround may be to use primitive string-processing functions like `substring-before()`, `substring-after()`, or `match()`. (The latter uses regular expressions and requires XPath 2.0.) Of course, many people will tell you not to use regular expressions to analyze markup like XML and HTML. For good reason: in the general case, it's very difficult to do it right (with regexes or with plain string searches). But for very restricted cases where the input is highly predictable, and in absence of better tools, it can be the best tool for a less-than-ideal job.

For example, for the data shown in your question, you could use

```
substring-before(substring-after(//description, 'img src="'), '"')
```

In this case, the inner call `substring-after(//description, 'img src="')` returns `pictureUrl.jpg" /></div>text for desc</div>`, of which the substring before `"` is `pictureUrl.jpg`.

This isn't really robust, for example it'll fail if there's a space between `src` and `=`. But if the exact formatting is predictable, you'll be OK.

Comment: thank you for your reply. How can I get the img source with substring-before() or substring-after(). Sorry I'm very new with xpath