# Determine if a node is a CDATA section

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get out value from XML node and running in problem with CDATA section.

My XML look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <Test>This is my node</Test>
    <HelpContent><![CDATA[this is the CDATA section]]></HelpContent>
</root>
```

with this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();      
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(currentFile);

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpathObj = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpathObj.compile("//*");

NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);      
int len = nodes.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    System.out.println("Node name [" + node.getNodeName() + "] of type [" + node.getNodeType() + "]");
    System.out.println("NodeValue: " + node.getNodeValue());
    System.out.println("TextContent: " + node.getTextContent());
}
```

I got the following:

```
> Node name [root] of type [1] 
> NodeValue: null 
> TextContent:      This is my
> node  this is the CDATA section
> 
> Node name [Test] of type [1] 
> NodeValue: null 
> TextContent: This is my node
> 
> Node name [HelpContent] of type [1] 
> NodeValue: null 
> TextContent: this is the CDATA section
```

As you can see, for node that has child (in this case only the root one) I got all text extracted from children nodes.
Additionally you can see that the getNodeType is always retuning 1 (ELEMENT_NODE)...

Question how could I get the value of node only if contains data like "Test" and "TextContent" but empty or null for node like "root"?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve element text inside CDATA markup via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath)

Comment: The linked duplicate explains that XPath ignores `CDATA` nodes. If you walk the DOM instead of using XPath, you should be able to find them.

Comment: In the DOM `node.getNodeValue()` for an element node is null. https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Core-20030226/DOM3-Core.html#core-ID-F68D080. You might want to show us a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the result you say you get, together with an explanation of the result you expect instead.

Comment: The linked duplicate seems to refer to fact that the CDATA literal is stripped but the value is returned...

Comment: @MartinHonnen yeap... I think that I messed up my original code; I've updated the question with samples

Comment: root node is not the only node to contain child..test and helpContent also have child nodes...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author yes, that is correct. My assumption was incorrect due to lack of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I come out with this solution... not sure if that is the correct way to do it but seems to work as expected.

So, to get the value for node like "Test" or "HelpContent" I updated the code with the following:

```
NodeList childs = node.getChildNodes();

if (childs.getLength() == 1){
    System.out.println("TextContent: " + node.getTextContent());
}
```