# From Oracle DB Extract the Value from CDATA based on Key

Tags: xml, oracle, cdata

My XML in the table as below

```
<fields><field key="2" val="5" type="D"/><![CDATA[<field key="3" val="SkpKSko=" 
type="T"></field>]]></fields>
```

I would like to get the value  of `SkpKSko=` by passing key as `3`

I was using the query

```
SELECT x.val  from Valuefromglobal ,xmltable('/fields/field[@key=2]' PASSING 
XMLFILED COLUMNS val VARCHAR2(400) PATH '@val' ) x
```

The above query gives me the result of `5` the expected answer.
However, if I change my argument to `@key=3` to fetch CDATA value which results 0 records.

Comment: <fields><field key="2" val="6" type="D"/><![CDATA[<field key="3" val="JJJJJ" type="T"></field>]]><![CDATA[<field key="4" val="This Seems to be Good" type="T"></field>]]></fields> is the sample  where under root tag i may have more than one CDATA with different keys

Comment: I don't think you can query into a CDATA element. See here maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could get the desired result if you extract the CDATA using XMLTABLE, and then pass it to the next XMLTABLE to get the VAL attribute.

```
select
  x2.val
from xmltable('/fields'
              passing xmltype('
                        <fields>
                          <field key="2" val="5" type="D"/>
                          <![CDATA[<field key="3" val="SkpKSko=" type="T">
                                   </field>]]>
                        </fields>
                      ')
              columns cdata varchar2(2048) path 'text()') as x1,
     xmltable('/field[@key=3]'
              passing xmltype(x1.cdata)
              columns val varchar2(30) path '@val') as x2;
```

**Output:**

```
VAL
--------
SkpKSko=
```

[DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c2085f7a7ec8ce6cc42466398ec6c14)