# Find option value by text in regex or xpath extractor

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

how to extract option value from text by regex or xpath from the below response

**xpath extractor**

```
 //*[@id="form_extsss:fromSerie2"]/option[text()='-DRIVE_ME']/@value
```

for example:

option value for -DRIVE_ME is 630 (expecting the 630 as final value)

**Response**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response>
   <changes>
      <update id="form_extsss"><![CDATA[<form id="form_extsss" name="form_extsss" 
      method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <select id="form_extsss:fromSerie2" name="form_extsss:fromSerie2" size="1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form_extsss:fromSerie2&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;form_extsss:fromSerie2&quot;,u:&quot;form_extsss&quot;});" style="width:110px">  <option value="-1">Select Series</option>   
        <option value="1384">-HAD</option>  
        <option value="630">-DRIVE_ME</option>
        </select>                       
                                    </form>]]></update>
      <update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[]]></update>
   </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Comment: Do you have a code example showing what you've attempted that isn't working how you expect?

Comment: @bryan i haven't tried by code ,still trying to achieve by regex or xpath as mention in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<option value="630">
```

The below Regular expression can be used in regular expression extractor:-

```
<option value="(.\d*)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xpath` won't work because of [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/how-do-i-retrieve-element-text-inside-cdata-markup-via-xpath) is represented as string only.

However if you have xquery available do

```
let $x := <partial-response>
    <changes>
      <update id="form_extsss"><![CDATA[<form id="form_extsss" name="form_extsss" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <select id="form_extsss:fromSerie2" name="form_extsss:fromSerie2" size="1"  onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form_extsss:fromSerie2&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;form_extsss:fromSerie2&quot;,u:&quot;form_extsss&quot;});" style="width:110px">
        <option value="-1">Select Series</option>   
        <option value="1384">-HAD</option>  
        <option value="630">-DRIVE_ME</option>
      </select>                       
                                </form>]]></update>
      <update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[]]></update>
    </changes>
  </partial-response>

return parse-xml($x/changes/update/text())/form/select/option/@value
```

Comment: thx for the reply am not  aware how to use xquery in jmeter but gud to know

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below regex helps with your scenerio:-
[image]
[image]